# Can't access POST/PUT/DELETE api but success access GET API in same url

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest, .htaccess

I create my own API using PHP and access it with Javascript. It's successful when the method is GET, but fails for other methods.

error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/test/api' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

here are my codes.

api.php

```
<?php
require_once "method.php";
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, X-JSON");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-with, Content_Type,Accept,Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type");

...
?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^api/?$ api.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/([0-9]+)/?$ api.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

script.js

```
function userDelete(id) {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("DELETE", "http://localhost/test/api");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ 
      "id": id
    }));
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
        const objects = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Swal.fire(objects['message']);
        loadTable();
      } 
    };
  }
```

Comment: Describe 'fails'. It's always important to add symptoms of the failure.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are status codes you receive from backend php.

Comment: @Evert Sorry, I have edited my question and added the error from the console

Comment: CORS isn't just about a couple of `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers. Using the `DELETE` method makes the request non-simple, requiring a preflight `OPTIONS` request that you'll need to respond to separately. You can do this with PHP or via configuration of your server (eg Apache, NGINX, etc)

Comment: What this error suggests is that when the OPTIONS request happens, you are not returning a `200 OK`.